# Rellich-Kondrachov theorem in dimension one

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators

Let $I:=(a, b)$ be an open interval, possibly unbounded. I'm reading below theorem in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*:

> **Theorem 8.8.** There exists a constant $C$ (depending only on $|I| \leq \infty)$ such that
> $$
> (5) \quad
> \|u\|_{L^{\infty}(I)} \leq C\|u\|_{W^{1, p}(I)} \quad \forall u \in W^{1, p}(I), \quad \forall 1 \leq p \leq \infty .
> $$
> In other words, $W^{1, p}(I) \subset L^{\infty}(I)$ with continuous injection for all $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Further, if $I$ is **bounded** then
>
> - $(6) \quad$ the injection $W^{1, p}(I) \subset C(\bar{I})$ is compact for all $1<p \leq \infty$,
> - $(7) \quad$ the injection $W^{1,1}(I) \subset L^q(I)$ is compact for all $1 \leq q<\infty$.

It seems to me we can extend $(7)$ to

> - $(8) \quad$ the injection $W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^q(I)$ is compact for all $1\le p \leq q<\infty$.

Could you confirm if $(8)$ is true and if my below attempt of proving it is fine?

---

We need the following results (in the same book), i.e.,

> **Notation** (shift of function). We set $\left(\tau_h f\right)(x)=f(x+h)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}^N$.
>
> **Theorem 4.26** (Kolmogorov-M. Riesz-Fréchet). Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a bounded set in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $1 \leq p<\infty$. Assume that $\lim _{|h| \to 0} \|\tau_h f-f\|_{L^p (\mathbb R^N)}=0$ uniformly in $f \in \mathcal{F}$, i.e., for each $\varepsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that $\|\tau_h f-f\|_{L^p (\mathbb R^N)}<\varepsilon$ for all  $f \in \mathcal{F}$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}^N$ with $|h|<\delta$. Then the closure of $\mathcal{F}_{\restriction \Omega}$ in $L^p(\Omega)$ is compact for any measurable set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with **finite** measure. [Here $\mathcal{F}_{\restriction \Omega}$ denotes the restrictions to $\Omega$ of the functions in $\mathcal{F}$.]
>
> **Proposition 8.5** Let $u \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ with $1<p<\infty$. The following statments are equivalent: (i) $u \in W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$. (ii) there exists a constant $C$ such that for all $h \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\|\tau_h u-u\|_{L^p (\mathbb R)} \leq C|h|$. Moreover, we can choose $C=\|u'\|_{L^p (\mathbb R)}$ in (ii). The implication (i) $\implies$ (ii) is also valid when $p = 1$
>
> **Theorem 8.6** (extension operator). Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. There exists a bounded linear operator $P: W^{1, p}(I) \rightarrow W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$, called an *extension operator*, such that for each $u \in W^{1, p}(I)$ we have $P u_{\restriction I}=u, \|P u\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} \leq C\|u\|_{L^p(I)}$ and $\|P u\|_{W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})} \leq C\|u\|_{W^{1, p}(I)}$ where $C$ depends only on $|I| \leq \infty$.

Let $\mathcal H$ be the closed unit ball of $W^{1,p} (I)$. We need to prove that $\mathcal H$ has a compact closure in $L^q (I)$. Let $P$ be the extension operator given by **Theorem 8.6**. Let $\mathcal F := \{Pu : u \in \mathcal H\} \subset W^{1,p} (\mathbb R)$. Then $\mathcal H = \mathcal F_{\restriction I}$ and $\mathcal F$ is bounded $W^{1, p}(\mathbb{R})$. In particular, $\mathcal F$ is bounded in $L^p (\mathbb R)$. By **Theorem 8.8**(5), $\mathcal F$ is bounded in $L^\infty (\mathbb R)$.  By [interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality?useskin=vector#Generalization_with_more_than_two_functions), $\mathcal F$ is bounded in $L^q (\mathbb R)$. By **Theorem 4.26**, it remains to prove $\lim _{|h| \to 0} \|\tau_h f-f\|_{L^q (\mathbb R)}=0$ uniformly in $f \in \mathcal{F}$.

By **Proposition 8.5**, we have for each $f \in \mathcal F$ that $\|\tau_h f-f\|_{L^p (\mathbb R)} \leq C|h|$ where $C := \sup_{f \in \mathcal F} \|f'\|_{L^p (\mathbb R)} \le \sup_{f \in \mathcal F} \|f\|_{W^{1, p} (\mathbb R)} < \infty$. By [interpolation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality?useskin=vector#Generalization_with_more_than_two_functions), we have for each $f \in \mathcal F$ that
$$
\begin{align*}
\|\tau_h f-f\|_{L^q (\mathbb R)}^q &\le \|\tau_h f-f\|_{L^p (\mathbb R)}^p \|\tau_h f-f\|_{L^\infty (\mathbb R)}^{q-p} \\
&\le C^p |h|^p (\|\tau_h f\|_{L^\infty (\mathbb R)} + \|f\|_{L^\infty (\mathbb R)})^{q-p} \\
&= C^p |h|^p (2 \|f\|_{L^\infty (\mathbb R)})^{q-p}.
\end{align*}
$$

The claim then follows.