# Let $I$ be an open bounded interval of $\mathbb R$. The injection $W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^q(I)$ is compact for any $p, q \in [1, \infty)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, compact-operators

Let $I$ be an open *bounded* interval of $\mathbb R$. I have recently proved in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4813153/rellich-kondrachov-theorem-in-dimension-one) thread that the injection $W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^q(I)$ is compact for all $1\le p \leq q<\infty$.

We fix $1\le r < p <\infty$. We have the injection $L^p (I) \subset L^r (I)$ is continuous. Combining this with the above result, we get that the injection $W^{1,p}(I) \subset L^q(I)$ is compact for any $p, q \in [1, \infty)$. This is quite surprising to me when I look at Rellich-Kondrachov [theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem).

Could you confirm if my above reasoning is fine?

Comment: No, this is normal, in dimension $1$, $p^*$ is always infinite, so every injection is subcritical, except $p=1$, $q=\infty$.

Comment: @LL3.14 Thank you so much for your verification!

Comment: If you don't know the classical picture, here it is in dimension $d$ http://laurent-lafleche.perso.math.cnrs.fr/images/GagNir.svg. The inside of the triangle contains compact embedding of $L^r\cap W^{1,p}$ in the whole space

Comment: In bounded domains, as soon as you are in some space, you are also on all the spaces on the right ...